# Find a positive integer such that half of it is a square,a third of it is a cube,and a fifth of it is a fifth power

Tags: number-theory

I found this problem in Underwood Dudley book in Linear congruence and Chineese remainder theorem ,but I can't present it as system of Linear congruence Anyone have any idea?
Please, help me

Comment: Similar: [What is the smallest integer greater than 1 such that ½
of it is a perfect square and ⅕
of it is a perfect fifth power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976181/what-is-the-smallest-integer-greater-than-1-such-that-frac12-of-it-is-a-perfe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A positive integer works if and only if it is of the form $2^a3^b5^cn^{30}$, and the following must hold:

$a\equiv 1 \bmod 2, 15|a$.

$b\equiv 1 \bmod 3,10|b$.

$c\equiv 1 \bmod 5,6|c$.

I found them by trial and error, but there are methods to solve them, (look up chinese remainder theorem.)

We get solutions: $a=15,b=10,c=6$

So $2^{15}3^{10}5^{6}$ works.

Comment: Sure, happy to help.

Answer (score 11):

I bet this is not what you were looking for, but it is worth mentioning that $0$ is a solution.

Comment: Probably better as a comment and not an answer, but maybe you don't have the reputation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/660973)

Comment: Though trivial, this is a valid answer.

Comment: At the time of posting my answer I did not have enough reputation points to post a comment. Also, I do not understand why @Hamza says that my post does not provide an answer to the question. The question does not imply that the solution has to be a non-zero integer. Therefore, 0 is a possible solution.

Comment: @Paquarian I think the reason is that while your answer is technically correct from a strict interpretation of the question title, it probably does not help Fourier in any way, and hence is not a useful answer.

Answer (score 7):

Guess that the number is of the form $2^{n_2} 3^{n_3} 5^{n_5}$. Then

$1)$ Since $n/2$ is a square
\begin{align}
n_2-1 \equiv 0 \mod 2\\
n_3 \equiv 0 \mod 2\\
n_5 \equiv 0 \mod 2\\
\end{align}
$2)$ Since $n/3$ is a cube
\begin{align}
n_2 \equiv 0 \mod 3\\
n_3-1 \equiv 0 \mod 3\\
n_5 \equiv 0 \mod 3\\
\end{align}
$3)$Since $n/5$ is a fifth power
\begin{align}
n_2 \equiv 0 \mod 5\\
n_3 \equiv 0 \mod 5\\
n_5-1 \equiv 0 \mod 5\\
\end{align}
Rewriting this, we have
\begin{align}
n_2 \equiv 0 \mod 15,\quad n_2 \equiv 1 \mod 2\\
n_3 \equiv 0 \mod 10, \quad n_3 \equiv 1 \mod 3\\
n_5 \equiv 0 \mod 6, \quad n_5 \equiv 1 \mod 5
\end{align}

Some trial and error can give you $n_2 = 15$, $n_3=10$, and $n_5=6$ as a simple solution (among many others). So $2^{15} 3^{10} 5^6$ is one solution.